Backup Dbeaver with postgres
I'm tring to apply backup using DBeaver with postgres:
1: Create backup:
enter image description here
2:
enter image description here
3: I try apply restore on another database and get this:
enter image description here
I got multiple error, some of them:
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "sec_client.ms_users_pin" does not exist

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "sec_client.link_apps_clients_log" does not exist

pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "sec_client.link_apps_clients_log" does not exist



and more or them, what's wrong??
I'm working with windows 11 and postgres 13, and using DBeaver
